# Expandable unordered list animation, rendering issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to animate an expandable list, but having trouble in correctly displaying list.
Without animation effect list is being displayed correctly (expand/collapse). To collapse list I am using `ul.style.visibility = "hidden"; ul.style.height = "0px";`. Without animation effect, list if looking fine:

[image: Correctly displayed unordered list].

The black borders are on UL element. I am using following Javascript code to expand the list:

```
var from = 0; //The height
ul.style.height = "auto";  //set height to auto to get actual height
var to = ul.offsetHeight; //get height
ul.style.height = "0px";
ul.style.visibility = "visible";
ul.style.overflow = "hidden";

var start = new Date().getTime(),
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/400);
        ul.style.height = (from+step*(to-from))+"px";
        if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
    },20);
//Expand List
ul.style.overflow = "inherit";
ul.style.height = "auto";
ul.style.visibility = "inherit";
```

`ul` in the code is reference to the `ul` elements in unordered list currently being expanded.

But after using this code to animate expand behavior, width of outer `ul` element is not changing with expand of inner `ul` element. However animation is working fine, but list is looking like this:

[image: Incorrectly displayed unordered list]

When I comment out `//ul.style.height = (from+step*(to-from))+"px";` from `setInterval`, list is being displayed correctly (however no animation effect).

Can you please point out error, why is not width of outer `ul` changing with expand of inner `ul`

Comment: Have you checked the debugger to see what the value of ul.offsetHeight is?  My guess is that this is zero or at least, not what you expect it to be, which is why it is not working correctly.  Try replacing var `to = ul.offsetHeight;` with `var to = 100;`, just to see if it works.

Comment: @Craig Checked, `ul.offsetHeight;` is returning correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't display correctly when the interval finishes is because you are assigning "auto" to ul.style.height before the interval has even run its first interval.  You should do this when the interval finishes:

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
    var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/400);
    if (1 === step) {
        ul.style.height = "auto";
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        ul.style.height = (from+step*(to-from))+"px";
    }
},20);
```